# BigQuery client python get column based partitioning column name

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

I am looking to include a where clause to an existing query to exclude data in the BigQuery streaming buffer.

To do this I would like to get the Partition column name so I can add

```
WHERE partition_column IS NOT NULL;
```

to my existing query.

I have been looking at the CLI and the get_table method however that just returns the value of the column not the column name.
I get the same when searching on `.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` this returns a field for partition_id but I would prefer the column name itself, is there away to get this ?

Additionally the table is setup with column based partitioning.

Comment: Why don't you use `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo column to apply your filter?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The  _PARTITIONTIME column doesn't exist when using column based partitioning, you get the pseudo columns when using Partition by ingestion time at table creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on python [BigQuery client documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html#google-cloud-bigquery-table-table), use the attribute `time_partitioning`:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
bq_table = client.get_table('my_partioned_table')
bq_table.time_partitioning # TimePartitioning(field='column_name',type_='DAY')
bq_table.time_partitioning.field # column_name
```

Small tips, if you don't know where to search, print the API repr:

```py
bq_table.to_api_repr()
```